Docker build does not finish
I am trying to build docker image for mssql in order to restore an existing database. The build does not finish. It won't. I tried several times, and it is always building. The first time I wait for 45 minutes without ending. I stopped by myself with ctrl+C

Here is my dockerfile content:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password123
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

COPY ./AdventureWorks2022.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/AdventureWorks2022.bak

RUN (/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Starting database restore" && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD -d master -i "RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2022 FROM DISK='/var/opt/mssql/backup/AdventureWorks2022.bak'"

Sure I am not docker guru, so I cannot find easily what is wrong.
I would want to know how to fix it and how to improve my Dockerfile.
Thanks

You're trying to RUN the database as part of the build process; the background process connected to a shell pipe doesn't seem like a correct combination.  In most cases you can't create a database image with preloaded data, due to images' volume setups; do you need a setup like Restore database in docker container or Restore SQL Server database to Linux Docker?

You seem to be trying to restore AdventureWorks2022.bak for SQL Server 2022 into an SQL Server 2019 container. Are you aware that older versions of SQL Server cannot restore backups taken from newer versions?

When you read the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation did you notice it linking to a tutorial about using an entrypoint.sh script to create a database? You can modify that to restore a database instead of creating one.

Thanks to @David-Maze and @AlwaysLearning
Here is my final Dockerfile I used to make it works.
# Use the official SQL Server 2022 image from Microsoft
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

# Set environment variables
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Password123
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

# Create directory for database backups
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/dbbackup; exit 0
WORKDIR $BACKUP_DIR

# Copy the database backup file to the container
COPY AdventureWorks2022.bak /usr/src/dbbackup/
COPY restore.sql /usr/src/dbbackup/

# Restore database during container build
RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" \
    && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i /usr/src/dbbackup/restore.sql \
    && pkill sqlservr

# Expose SQL Server port
EXPOSE 1433

# Start SQL Server when the container starts
CMD ["/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr"]

And my restore.sql
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2022;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks2022] FROM DISK=N'/usr/src/dbbackup/AdventureWorks2022.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, STATS = 5, REPLACE, MOVE N'AdventureWorks2022' TO N'/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks2022.mdf', MOVE N'AdventureWorks2022_log' TO N'/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks2022_log.ldf';
GO

I am sure it can be improved. This could really be a good start if it needs to keep simple
